# Gstreamer Error: Pipeline could not be constructed: syntax error

Tags: linux, batch-file, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

I am trying to stream video data from a Raspberry Pi Zero W to a PC running Windows 10.  I used this video as my source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNvYanDLHZA and this was the code I used (using my PC's actual IP address rather than the 10.30.0.0 I pretend here) :

Raspberry Pi Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
raspivid -n -t 0 -rot 270 -w 960 -h 720 -fps 30 -b 6000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvvv fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=5 ! udpsink host=10.30.0.0 port=5000
```

Windows batch script:

```
cd C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false
```

However, after running this my batch script crashes.  The error I am getting is on the "`gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5000`" part, and it is:

> ERROR: Pipeline could not be constructed: syntax error

Any ideas what I can do to correct this? Thanks

Comment: I tested your receiving side script on Ubuntu and it works fine on my sistem. Is your installation complete?

Comment: Yes, it is. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it twice on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to make some minor changes on the receiver pipeline and unless it works also in the receiver.

I haven't tested with the raspberry pi source, but I take for granted that the your source pipeline is correct. The main issue is that it is strictly necessary to put the **caps** on the source pad of the **udpsrc** plugin, using the *caps* property:

Your pipeline should be something like this:

> gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 **caps="application/x-rtp,
>   media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000,
>   encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96"** ! rtpjitterbuffer !
>   rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! **videoconvert** ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false
>   text-overlay=false

Also consider putting *videoconvert* plugin after *avdec_h264* if the pipeline doesn't work. If you don't know what plugin is necessary you always can use *decodebin* which is very useful.

You can always make a closed-loop for testing purposes like this:

**TX (which is rather similar to your source):**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v videotestsrc is-live=true ! x264enc bitrate=1000 tune=zerolatency ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=5 ! udpsink host=10.30.0.0 port=5000
```

**RX:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Comment: If I try your bottom fix for RX, I get this error:

ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Could not get/set settings from/on resource.
Additional debug info:
gstudpsrc.c(1561): gst_udpsrc_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
bind failed: Error binding to address: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

Comment: Your port is not reachable for Windows. This has nothing to do with the question. Please fix it before continuing.

Comment: Alright. I have very little experience using command prompt in Windows. How do I fix my port to make it reachable?

Comment: I tried allowing the port (port 5000) in Windows firewall, but still got the same error.

Comment: Just check that you can ping your raspberry pi from windows and vice versa. Even disable firewall if it's necessary. Nothing more can be solved from here regarding to the network problems.

Comment: Wow, this is so frustrating! I can get my raspberry pi and laptop to ping each other successfully if I turn my firewall completely off, but I still get the same error I just described in which the "pipeline doesn't want to pause".

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I went to my windows command prompt and typed 
    netstat-an | find "UDP" | more

This brought up a list of the busy UDP ports, and I discovered that Port 5000 was one of them.  So I used a different port instead and my video stream came through!!